# Json.NET vs Newtonsoft.Json SerializationBinder is different

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, mono, json.net

I know there are many similar questions in this topic, yet I did not find my answer here.

*I have downloaded `Json.net` in Unity and `Newtonsoft.json` as a NuGet package in a different project. The `Newtonsoft.json` is working and I tried to use this working solution in a Unity project.*

*I **need** to use `ISerializationBinder` for converting an abstract class hierarchy and I want to serialize/deserialize the classnames **only**, and not their full assembly name. (Reason for that is that the C# code should communicate with a different program.)*

I use a solution that has the following class for serializing (copied from an official example online):

```
public class KnownTypesBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    public IList<Type> KnownTypes { get; set; }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        return KnownTypes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == typeName);
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        typeName = serializedType.Name;
    }
}
```

`ISerializationBinder` does not exist in `Json.net`. The `JsonSerializerSettings` is clearly different:

`Newtonsoft.json`:

```
public class JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    public ISerializationBinder SerializationBinder { get; set; }
}
```

`Json.net`:

```
public class JsonSerializerSettings
{
    public SerializationBinder Binder { get; set; }
}
```

`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder` (is not derived from `ISerializationBinder`) has no method called `public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)`, which means the type name cannot be defined.

- So, how can I solve the serialization - by using only the class names - in Unity? (Only setting `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,` is no solution here)
- Why does everyone claim that they are the same when it is clearly not the case? (Even the StackOverflow tag below for `Json.net` does that.)
- Does the difference have anything to do with the fact that Unity uses Mono?

Thanks.

Comment: Json.NET vs Newtonsoft.Json are the same thing.   You must be trying to use the same code with different versions of Json.NET.  In [Json.NET 10.0.1](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2017/03/21/json-net-10-0-release-1-async-performance-documentation-and-more) Newtonsoft *Added ISerializationBinder* and *Obsoleted SerializationBinder* so if you try to backport code written against 10.0.1 or later to an earlier version you'll encounter a compatibility problem.

Comment: @dbc so `Json.net 8.0.3` version is the same as  `Newtonsoft.json 8.0.3`? And do you happen to know why `[System.Runtime.InteropServices, System.Runtime.Serialization (SerializationBinder)]` is different? The unity version's class is missing the `BindToName` function there.

Comment: 1)  Yes -- but I believe there are no official builds of Json.NET for Unity3d from Newtonsoft.  Instead there are 3rd party builds based off of specific versions of Json.NET so maybe you're using one? 2) [`SerializationBinder.BindToName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder?view=netframework-4.0) was first introduced in .Net 4.0.  If your Unity is using an earlier version, you won't have it.

Comment: 3) Incidentally, inconsistencies in `SerializationBinder` between .Net versions were why Newtonsoft replaced it with [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Switched to `.NET 4.x Equivalent` but the `BindToName` method is not called. I wonder if Json.net knows about this function at all or it was written for the earlier C# version.

Comment: Earlier versions of Json.NET used conditional compilation to choose whether to call `BindToName` as shown in https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/8.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ReflectionUtils.cs#L154.  So it really depends on how your Unity3d-specific Json.NET DLL was compiled.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this. However I guess it's going to be painful to solve this. I need to map the `$type` between simple and full name or determine the parsed type from a different field than `$type`. Even the abstract `JsonConverter` clss cannot map the values *before* determining the type that needs to be parsed and `$type` seems to be a fixed name. I am guessing I need to map the whole json hierarchy "by hand" and convert all `$type` fields between simple and full type. But there must be a better solution.

Comment: The real problem is that you have a build of Json.NET earlier than version 10.0 AND compiled for a version of .Net earlier than 4.0.  If you can modify either of those circumstances you'll be OK.  1() If your Json.NET is version 10.0.1 or later you can use `ISerializationBinder.BindToName` which will work even on .Net 3.5.  2) Or if you can get a build of Json.NET 8.0.3 that is targeted against .net 4.0 or later you can use `SerializatinBinder.BindToName`.  Either way your problem becomes fixable.  So, can you find a more recent build of Json.NET for unity?  Or build one yourself?

Comment: @dbc As simple as it may sound, it was really just a difference in versions. I added the Newtonsoft 11.0.2 and the program ran successful. Do you happen to know what would happen on non-windows machines? Would it run on any platform just as well? Anyway, thanks for your help. Just write an answer if you want the points.

Answer (score 1):

This is a versioning issue. The `JSON .NET for Unity` you are referring to as just `Json.NET` uses (as mentioned in the comments) Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3.

If you want to use fresh features from Newtonsoft.Json I suggest jumping to a different solution. The currently most up-to-date fork of Newtonsoft.Json made for Unity is here: https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity#readme, being at Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 at the time of writing.

jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity is also deployed via the builtin Unity Package Manager, so staying up-to-date will be easier as a user as well.