# How to deserialize string with json.net - are there two versions of the library?

Tags: json, .net-core, json.net, nuget-package, monodevelop

I want to deserialize a string (json) to an object (i'd like dynamic).

I use monodevelop and nuget packages

I have been looking for Json.net but also found Newtonsoft.Json.

And I could make a JArray by *using* Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.

I read on

[Json.NET vs Newtonsoft.Json SerializationBinder is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307935/json-net-vs-newtonsoft-json-serializationbinder-is-different)

that these are two versions of the same library?

The main goal is to convert Json to Yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is most likely the one you want.  It has been known as "Json.Net" since it was first [released](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2006/07/06/Json.NET-1.0.1-released) in 2006 and has many features, including the [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObject, JArrays, etc.).

However, in December 2018 (after the question you referenced was asked), another author unaffiliated with Newtonsoft released a [completely different library](https://github.com/obarlik/Json.Net/wiki/Json.Net's-Home) on NuGet and called it Json.Net so now there is confusion.  This other library advertises itself as a "A Minimalistic JSON handler" so it intentionally does not have very many features.  It definitely does not have support for JArrays.

Comment: Thanks @Brianrogers, I accept your answer without question